# Dump NSUserDefaults on app exit?

Tags: objective-c

I'm using NSUserDefaults to hold some data while my app is running, but I want to dump all the  data on app termination. Is this possible, and if so how do I do this? Thanks!
~Carpetfizz
I know that there's this, but I'm not sure where to put it. Should it go in the app delegate?

```
    NSString *appDomain = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleIdentifier];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] removePersistentDomainForName:appDomain];



- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application
{


   // NSString *appDomain = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleIdentifier];
    //[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] removePersistentDomainForName:appDomain];

    [NSUserDefaults resetStandardUserDefaults];





}
```

Comment: What's the point of using NSUserDefault when you don't want to keep these data from one session to the next?

Comment: I'm using an SSH library that requires authentication everytime a command is executed. So I found it faster to just store the values such as username, pass, when the form is entered then retrieve them across the application.

Comment: You shouldn't use NSUD for that, use the Keychain

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Security/Conceptual/keychainServConcepts/iPhoneTasks/iPhoneTasks.html

Comment: `applicationWillTerminate:` is not called for most apps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're doing is hacky and it's a bad idea for app maintainability :-). NSUserDefaults is meant for persistent storage (across app starts). You are holing yourself into a path where you can't ever user NSUserDefaults to store persistent settings. You should consider creating a new class that contains the "temporary" information you're stuffing into NSUserDefaults.

Try something like this:

```
@interface MyAppSettings : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *userName;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *authenticationToken;
@end

@implementation MyAppSettings
@end
```

Comment: Using User Defaults to store session only state that must be initialized at next launch is never the right answer.

Answer (score 1):

The answer for your question is: you should use `NSUserDefaults`' class method:

```
+ (void)resetStandardUserDefaults
```

on the `ApplicationDelegate`'s method:

```
- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application
```

But a better question is: Why are you using `NSUserDefaults` if you want to dump all the information you've stored after the app finishes executing? It would be better to have all the information stored on an object (maybe a Singleton?) instead of using `NSUserDefaults` .

Comment: Thanks, but that didn't do anything, did I implement it wrong? See my latest edit

Comment: How are you testing it? How is your app being terminated? Is this method being called?

Comment: Is `applicationWillTerminate` being called when the app is in background?

Comment: `applicationWillTerminate:` is often not called.  That'll never work consistently.   The answer is your *better question* part.  Cut the NSUD stuff out entirely.